# how to merge csv cells by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe.

[image]

I want it transform it to below with merging cells with same value in a column

[image]

Anyone can provide some sample code?

Comment: you can use groupby()

Comment: do you think merge rows in excel?

Comment: Yes. my goal is to merge the cells

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(['A', 'B']),['A', 'B']]=''
```

Get duplicate values and mask the values to empty string.

I/P:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  A
1  1  a  B
2  2  b  C
3  2  b  A
```

O/P:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  A
1        B
2  2  b  C
3        A
```

note: You can't exactly merge cells using pandas, the idea is suppressing values except first record

Comment: Hi Mohamed,  I tried with         df_merge = df.loc[df.duplicated(['si', 'cn', 'ci', 'ui', 'module_behavior', 'features_behavior', 'at']),['si', 'cn', 'ci', 'ui', 'module_behavior', 'features_behavior', 'at']]=' ',  but I didn;t get the similar output like what you posted. Is the code correct?

Comment: Don't need to save into df_merge. Remove assignment. Just print df, you will the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data generated by @mohamed thasin ah,

```py
df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
```

```py
    A   B   C
0   1   a   A, B
1   2   b   C, A
```

so try:

```
df.groupby(['cd', 'ci', 'ui', 'module_behavior', 'feature_behavior', 'at']).agg(', '.join)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output that you want seems to be an Excel file. If that is the case, I suggest :

```
df.groupby(['cn', 'ci', 'ui', 'module_behaviour', 'feature_behaviour', 'at']).apply(
lambda x: x.sort_values('caseid')).to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Pandas will `groupby` those columns and turn them into mutilevel indexes, and `to_excel` saves the `DataFrame` to an Excel file with the default setting `merge_cells=True`.